# How to do order by case when on sphinx?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

How can I set column priority for sphinx search? In custom mysql code, as following codes. How can I re-code it as sphinx search?

```
$orderBy = "ORDER BY 
                        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(n.eser_adi, '/', 1) LIKE '% $termsAsil %' THEN 1
                           WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(n.eser_adi, '/', 1) LIKE '$terms' THEN 2
                           WHEN n.konu_basliklari LIKE '% $termsAsil %'  THEN 3
                           WHEN n.konu_basliklari LIKE '$terms'  THEN 4
                           WHEN yazar_adi LIKE '% $termsAsil %'  THEN 5
                           WHEN yazar_adi LIKE '$terms'  THEN 6    
                           WHEN n.isbn LIKE '% $termsAsil %'  THEN 7
                           WHEN n.isbn LIKE '$terms'  THEN 8
                           WHEN yer_numarasi LIKE '$termsAsil%' THEN 9
                           ELSE 10
                        END ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well technically you can put the expression in the SELECT section

```
sphinxQL> SELECT id,IF(col=2,1,2) as mysort FROM index ORDER BY mysort ASC
```

Note, there isnt an CASE statement, would use IF() to the same effect.

But there are no LIKE or indeed SUBSTRING_INDEX function, so it wouldn't translate over.

However you look like there are search terms, so could manipulate the query so as to effect the calculated weight. Can also use Field-Weights adjust relative weights.

```
sphinxQL> SELECT id FROM index WHERE
  MATCH('$terms (@eser_adi ^terms | @eser_adi ^terms | @eser_adi "^terms$" | @konu_basliklari $termsAsil)')
```

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setfieldweights